# DateADD() when the date is in INT

Tags: sql

I am trying to use DateAdd() but my date is in INT. I know about Convert () but I am not sure what I am doing wrong:
    select DATEADD(dd,-60,convert(datetime,20161231))

It throws: "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime". Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast your int as a string first.  The dashes in the dates are optional... just more readable

```
select DATEADD(dd,-60,cast(20161231 as varchar(10)))
```

Returns

```
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000
```

Just for fun, try the following

```
Select cast('2016-12-31' as date)
      ,cast('20161231'   as date)
```